# Linux Operating system-NOT A KERNEL CHANGE

Tags: ubuntu, grub, linux-kernel

I tried to make an operating system with my on custom built kernel. It didn't work out to well. I am using ubuntu and have downloaded linux 3.2.7 from kernel.org . I am not trying to change the kernel in my ubuntu system. I want to make my own os with Grub, the linux kernel and i want to be able to have this homebrew os in a file type (such as iso) that I can put on a cd and boot on another computer. My question is : what exactly do I do to make this os? Any comments or tutorials would be helpful.